# Adding multiple comma separated values to a MySQL row using Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

i have this piece of code:

```
if (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    my $related_id = $ref->{'products_id'};
    my $sql = "REPLACE INTO products_xsell (products_id, xsell_id) 
        VALUES (".$product_id.", ".$related_id.")";
    $dbh->do($sql);
    $c_processed++;
}
```

At the moment, the data looks like this:

```
product_id   product_id
9999            22
8888            21
9999            66
7777            77
9999            88
```

I want to store the data like this:

```
product_id   product_id
9999            22,66,88
8888            21
7777            77
```

I have been reading about using `JOIN` but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I inherited this code and it is not using prepared statements and placeholders.
I hope to sort this out once I get the hang of Perl.

Comment: You may want to make sure you are familiar with the schema before you try to change the data like this. The example table you have here looks a lot like a foreign key map table (to map items in table A to items in table B and vice-versa), and what you're thinking of doing won't really work out if that's the case.

Comment: What you are proposing is a really terrible way to store the data.  Unless your boss is holding a gun to your head forcing you to format the data that way, I recommend you reconsider your design.  You could ask a question on this site about how to format the data to meet your needs instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll caution against 'data munging' in perl, when you've got a database - almost invariable, it's better to do this 'database side' - after all, that's what databases are *for*.

But to answer your general question - what you need is a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

#our hash
my %combined;

#header row - grabs first line and prints it. 
print scalar <DATA>; 

#iterates line by line
while ( <DATA> ) {
   #removes linefeeds
   chomp;
   #splits on whitespace. 
   my ($key, $value ) = split;
   #stores in combined hash of arrays.  
   push ( @{$combined{$key}}, $value ); 
}

#cycle through our hash, extracting each key and 
#merge the array into a string, comma delimited. 
foreach my $prod ( sort keys %combined ) { 
    print join ("\t", $prod, join ( ",", @{$combined{$prod}} ) ),"\n";
}


__DATA__
product_id   product_id
9999            22
8888            21
9999            66
7777            77
9999            88
```

Given your db query is returning a hashref, then you don't need the 'split' part as above - as you've effectively already done it. This code is intended to illustrate the technique (and not least because I don't have your DB, so this way we get a runnable example).